# Speech Recognition is not working in Android 11+

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-recognition-api

I using speech recognition google API its working fine in Android 10 and below but unfortunately stop working after updating API to android 30, and
Method Provide null result

```
  @Override
   public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
          ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = partialResults.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
          String result;
           if (stringArrayList != null) {
                result = stringArrayList.get(0);
                String stringBuilder = oldText + result;
                editText.setText(stringBuilder);
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
           }
  }
```

**and logcat response**

```
E/SpeechRecognizer: bind to recognition service failed
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be related to this [**new Android 11 "feature"**](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility), and the solution could be to add a query to the manifest for the blocked intent :

```
<manifest ...>
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

**Please let me know the results.**